# Select optimal set of samples to approximate a curve with predetermined number of samples?

Tags: javascript, c++, optimization, statistics, curve-fitting

### Background

I have a pet project that I love to overthink from time to time.  The project has to do with an RC aircraft control input device.  People familiar with that hobby are probably also familiar with what is known as "stick expo", which is a common feature of RC transmitters where the control sticks are either more or less sensitive near the neutral center position and become less or more sensitive as the stick moves closer to its minimum or maximum values.

I've read some papers that I don't fully understand.  I clearly don't have the math background to solve this, so I'm hoping that perhaps one of you might.

### Problem

I have decided to approximate the curve by taking a pre-determined number of samples and use linear interpolation to determine output values for any input values between the sample points.  *I'm trying to find a way to determine the most optimal set of sample points.*

If you look at this example of a typical growth curve for this application, you will notice that some sections are more linear (straighter), and some are less linear (more curvy).

[image: typical curve example]

These samples are equally distant from each other, but they don't have to be.  It would be smart to increase the sample density where there is more change and thereby increasing the resolution in the curvy segments by borrowing redundant points from the straight segments.

Is it possible to quantify the degree of error?  If it is, then is it also possible to determine the optimal set of samples for a given function and a pre-determined number of samples?

### Reference Code

Snippet from the class that uses a pre-calculated set of points to approximate an output value.

```cpp
/* This makes the following assumptions:
 *   1. The _points[] data member contians at least 2 defined Points.
 *   2. All defined Points have x and y values between MIN_VALUE and MAX_VALUE.
 *   3. The Points in the array are ordered by ascending values of x.
 */
int InterpolatedCurve::value( int x ) {
  if( _points[0].x >= x ) { return _points[0].y; }
  for( unsigned int i = 1; i < _point_count; i++ ) {
    if( _points[i].x >= x ) {
      return map(x, _points[i-1].x, _points[i].x,
                    _points[i-1].y, _points[i].y);
    }
  }
  // This is an error condition that is not otherwise reported.
  // It won't happen as long as the points are set up correctly.
  return x;
}

// Example map function (borrowed from Arduino site)
long map( long x, long x1, long x2, long y1, long y2 ) {
  return (x - x1) * (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) + y1;
}
```

Although my project is actually in C++, I'm using a Google spreadsheet to produce some numbers while I ponder this problem.

```js
// x: Input value between -1 and 1
// s: Scaling factor for curve between 0 (linear) and 1 (maximum curve)
// c: Tunable constant
function expo_fn( x, s, c ) {
  s = typeof s !== 'undefined' ? s : 1.0;
  c = typeof c !== 'undefined' ? c : 4.0;
  var k = c * ((c - 1.0) * s*s*s + s)/c + 1.0;
  return ((k - 1.0) * x*x*x*x*x + x)/k;
};
```

The following creates a set of isometrically distributed (non-optimal) points between input values -1 and 1.  These output values were expanded to integers between -16383 and 16383 for the above example spreadsheet.  Factor is a value between 0 and 1 that determines the "curviness"--zero being a flat, linear curve and 1 being the least-linear curve I care to generate.

```js
function Point( x, y ) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
};

function compute_points_iso( count, factor ) {
  var points = [];
  for( var i = 0; i < count; ++i ) {
    var x = 2.0/(count - 1.0) * i - 1.0;
    var y = expo_fn(x, factor);
    points.push(new Point(x,y));
  }
  return points;
};
```

### Relevant Academic Work

I have been studying [this paper](http://www.idav.ucdavis.edu/func/return_pdf?pub_id=272) describing an algorithm for selecting significant data points, but my program doesn't quite work right yet.  I will report back if I ever get this thing working.

Comment: this is not a timely comment since your question is 7.5 years old, but if the function is "polynomial-like" I would recommend Chebyshev approximation, in which case choosing points at the [Chebyshev nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_nodes) are somewhat better than equally-spaced; they are more concentrated towards the ends of the interval.

Comment: @JasonS I had not seen that algorithm. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to realize that you can bound the error on your linear interpolation in terms of the second derivative of the function.  I.e. if we approximate `f(x) \approx f(x_0) + f'(x_0)*(x-x_0)`, then the error in this approximation is less than `abs[ 0.5*f''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2 ]`.

The outline of an iterative approach could look like this:

1. Construct an initial, e.g. uniformly spaced, grid
2. Compute the second derivative of the function on this grid.
3. Compute the bound on the error using the second-derivative and the inter-sample spacing
4. Move the samples closer together where the error is large; move them further apart where the error is small.

I'd expect this to be an iterative solution that loops on steps 2,3,4.

Most of the details are in step 4.
For a fixed number of sample points one could use the median of the error bounds to select
where finer/coarser sampling is required (i.e. those locations where the error is larger than the median error will have the sample points pulled closer together).

Let `E_0` be this median of the error bounds; then we can, for each sample in the point, compute a new desired sample spacing `(dx')^2=2*E_0/f''(x)`; then you'd need some logic to go through and change the grid spacing so that it is closer to these ideal spacings.

My answer is influenced by having used the "Self-Organizing Map" algorithm on data; this or related algorithms may be relevant for your problem.   However, I can't recall ever
seeing a problem like yours where the goal is to make your estimates of the error uniform across the grid.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your notation--could you explain that a bit, please?  I may wind up having to go learn some new math concepts to follow.

Comment: Look up "Taylor series" in any calculus text book;  it should cover all of this, including the error bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will look that up.  Does `f'` and `f''` in your answer amount to "first derivative" and "second derivative"?  `abs` is obviously absolute value.  What is `dx'`?

Comment: dx' is the new inter-sample spacing that we'd like to have